# Angular Firebase and AngularFireDatabase

Tags: database, angularfire

In the angular firebase, I came across following two things:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

If both can be used for interacting with the database, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line imports the [AngularFire2 library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs).

The second line imports the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), which is what AngularFire uses under the hood.